¿Por qué me marca error en la palabra React?

Es un archivo .jsx
import React from 'react'

const SignUp = () => {
  return (
    <div>SignUp</div>
  )
}

export default SignUp


Si le pasas el ratón por encima un rato seguramente te lo diga... pero vamos, es que no lo estás usando.

Podrías contar que IDE estás usando. Probablemente te aparece marcado en rojo porque no lo estás usando o porque tu IDE no sabe acerca de la existencia de la librería.

Podemos ver que te marca error, pero no nos dices qué error te muestra (si acaso te muestra alguno). Por favor haz clic en [edit] y añade más detalles a tu pregunta. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour].

Antiguamente se necesitaba importar react para poder usar react, pero a partir de react 17 ya no lo necesitas en componentes sencillos como este, mira estos 2 articulos que te lo explican: https://dev.to/titungdup/you-no-longer-need-to-import-react-from-react-3pbj https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/say-goodbye-react-imports-17s-game-changing-feature-deepak-sharma-/
